# iis 7 and .net framework 4.0 beta 2

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, .net-4.0-beta-2

I am trying to get a  asp.net 4.0 beta 2. website running that is working on my dev machine, but not when I published to my server. Where I get the HTTP 500.22 error when using the 4.0 as application pool and "Integrated" in "Managed Pipeline Mode".

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Anders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting this in your `web.config` file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
</system.webServer>
```